# How to run C++ program/the executable file of the program from Node.js once it is hosted on Heroku?

Tags: c++, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have a C++ program that takes a bmp image as input, does color quantization and produces another bmp image as output. I wanted to make this a web application. I'm using React.js and Node.js for it.

I'll get the image from the user and store it locally in the server using multer, then I'll execute the exe of the C++ program and get the output image. Once the output image is generated, I'll pass that to React.

Everything works fine locally, but when hosted on heroku, it's not working.

There's a problem with executing the exe file of the program as far as I can tell.

Comment: How do you build the application? How is heroku configured? Heroku supports Linux application. _exe_ sounds like Windows

Comment: I compiled the C++ program using "g++ -o main.cpp" in the terminal. This gave me an executable file. I was able to locally run this executable from nodejs using "exec('main.exe')". So, I directly added this exe file to the repository.

Comment: That won't work. Heroku runs Linux. You can't build a Windows executable, deploy it to a Linux system and run it. It won't work. You should build it on the Heroku machine or at least on a similar Linux system.

Comment: Yeah. Got it. Can you help me do it? I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to build it on your own Linux machine or on a Heroku machine? I've never built a C++ project on Heroku.

Comment: I want to compile the C++ program on Heroku, then use the executable from nodejs. I saw that it's doable by using "heroku-builpack-make" script. I'll try and let you know. Thanks :)